# Injecting Spring managed prototype bean into non-spring managed classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, prototype

I've my Logger bean configured as below, for some specific requirements I need to access the Logger into some of the classes that are not managed by Spring. I've done the following steps to do so.

```
@bean
@scope("prototype")
Logger logger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMethodParameter().getContainingClass());
}
```

I'm trying to inject the logger bean into a non-spring class using the below line.

LOGGER = SpringApplicationContext.getBean(Logger.class);

And my SpringApplicationContext class is below

```
@component
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        // store ApplicationContext reference to access required beans later on
        SpringApplicationContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

Since the Logger is a prototype with InjectionPoint argument, I'm getting this error **No current InjectionPoint available for method 'logger' parameter 0**.

Can someone help to fix this or is there a better way to inject prototype beans with InjectionPoint argument into non-spring classes??